# Python Storing Multiple User Input in an Object followed by Array

Tags: python

I am new to python.

From my understanding, i am trying to let user create their own multiple choice question with the use of classes and objects.

I have created a class

```
class questionc:
    def __init__ (self, question, option1, option2, option3, answer):
        self.question = question
        self.option1 = option1
        self.option2 = option2
        self.option3 = option3
        self.answer = answer
```

Thereafter, i tried to create a method to ask user to input their questions.

```
from question import *

question_mcq= [ 

    ]

def createMCQ():
    noOfQuestions = int(input("How many questions are there in total: "))
    arrayIndex = 0
    while noOfQuestions != 0:
        question = input("Type in your question: ")
        option1 = input("Enter your MCQ choices: ")
        option2 = input("Enter your MCQ choices: ")
        option3 = input("Enter your MCQ choices: ")
        answer = input("Enter the correct answer: ")

        question_mcq= [
            questionc(question, option1, option2, option3, answer)
            ]

        #questionMix = questionc(qeustion, option1, option2, option3, answer)
        #question_mcq.insert = (arrayIndex, questionMix)
        noOfQuestions  -= 1
        arrayIndex += 1

    for number in range(len(question_mcq)):
        print(question_mcq[number].question)
        print(question_mcq[number].option1)
        print(question_mcq[number].option2)
        print(question_mcq[number].option3)
        #userAnswer = input("Enter you option 1, 2 or 3")

createMCQ()
```

As of now, from my understanding, the array that i created to store the object will get replaced by the latest user input. Hence i tried to add in an index. However, irregardless of using append or insert, the error: **"AttributeError: 'list' object attribute 'insert' is read-only"** occurs

```
        question_mcq.insert = [arrayIndex,
            questionc(question, option1, option2, option3, answer)
            ]
```

Comment: Your last piece of code is not valid usage of `insert`. Try `question_mcq.insert(arrayIndex,questionc(your_parameters))`

Comment: More [info](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) on python lists.

Comment: My goodness, thank you so much. Didnt realise my mistake till now. Spent almost 2hrs on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`insert()` is a method, not a property. That means that you have to invoke it like a function.

So in your case, you should use

```py
    question_mcq.insert(arrayIndex, questionc(question, option1, option2, option3, answer))
```

You can read more about lists in python3 [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Answer (score 0):

Deshpande012 definitely has the right solution with the mentioning of insert() being a method, and not a property. So the use is improper and it must be used like a function. This answer also includes the use of questionc() directly in the code rather than declaring a variable for questionc's return.

```
question_mcq.insert(arrayIndex, questionc(question, option1, option2, option3, answer))
```

For Python multiple choice you can then take the question, the answers, and the actual answer and store them in lists like below (this is a very primitive example that does not demonstrate answer shuffling or randomness with the correct answer):

```
questions = {
 "What is 15*3?":{"correct":"a", "answers":[45,35,60,40,30]},
 "What is 17 * 2?":{"correct":"b", "answers":[43,34,36,32,30]},
 "What is 19 * 3?":{"correct":"e", "answers":[58,48,55,59,57]},
 "What is 22 * 7?":{"correct":"c", "answers":[168,152,154,156,161]}
}
```

From there you can generate the code for a multiple choice quiz with Python. Whether this happens in the same script or in another file for anyone actually taking the user's saved quiz is up to you! Either way, you can clearly see how simple it is to take a set of stored answers and fake options to generate a Python quiz output. You just need to have the question settings stored and then obviously be able to interpret and evaluate scores for quiz answers.

https://nerdi.org/programming/python/python-multiple-choice/

That beginner Python tutorial goes over everything with some simple looping and known data structures. However, to take the tutorial a step further I really think that it's important to make sure the correct answer is shuffled with as much randomness as possible for each time the quiz is taking. In addition to that change I really do think it's worth it to also make sure you are storing multiple choice quiz settings (initial quiz creation) in either a database or in a file with a much slimmer data structure that your quiz generator can easily read and use dynamically with its own code. Of course from there you could consider storing user answers, having users log in to access their quiz results, etc.